# Why web.api getting null values when i send array of objects through ajax POST?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

following is the JSON data which i need to send to web.api

```
var array = [{
    "FeederName": "Test Feeder 1",
    "Status": "Up",
    "FeederCode": "FDR012341",
    "TimeStamp": "10-10-2018 23:24:43"
},
{
    "FeederName": "Test Feeder 2",
    "Status": "Down",
    "FeederCode": "FDR012342",
    "TimeStamp": "10-10-2018 11:24:43"
}]
```

This is the code I wrote to send the above JSON data to some `url`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    //contentType: 'application/json',
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    data: { "": array }, (or) json.stringfy(array) // I tried both, not working
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        console.log(data + date);
    }
})
```

My problem is when I send that data to API, all the values are going to `null` but i can get no.of objects:2. Please help me regarding this, i'm struggling since 2 days. Thanks.

Note: When i tried through `postman` it working fine.

> **Update**

1. Content[image: Content]
2. Body [image: Body]
3. Generated Code [image: Generated Code]

Comment: try to use        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                        console.log('status2 ' + jqXHR.status);
                        console.log('response2 ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                        console.log('exception2  ' + exception);
                    } in your ajax call and check what is the error

Comment: but, there is no error. Because request is going to server and returning no.of records effected. But, Only null data inserting.

Comment: You can copy your request in the form of ajaxRequst  from postman via **code** facility. so you can compare your ajax request with that. May be that will help out something.

Comment: Please show the web api controller method

Comment: @Dipal, Thanks. I gone through it i'm able to convert my request in to code. But, if i placed headers then im getting error like "405 (Method Not Allowed)" and "Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.". If i removed it null data passing to API.

Comment: @MarcusHöglund, that's remote person giving me the API. So i too don't know the controller method.

Comment: ok, how do you send it through postman? which contentType, how do you specify the body etc?

Comment: @Chanikya : well I think you have to tell your API developer to allow CORS in your apis(cross-origin resource sharing).

Comment: @MarcusHöglund I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please copy paste below code and check.You have many typos in your code may that was the issue.

```
$.ajax({
                method: "POST", // this should be method instead of type
                 url: url,
                content-type: "application/json",
                crossDomain : true,
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(array)
                success: function (data) {
                    var date = new Date();
                    console.log(data + date);
                }
      })
```

- you declared your data as **aary** and passing json.stringfy(**array**);
- json.stringfy() in that **json** should be capital **JSON**
- in ajax request there should be **method** instead of **type**

Update: changed arry to array.